# Extract value from pandas dataframe based on two condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe, `df1` and `df2`

```
df1 = A B
      1 a
      1 
      1 5
      1 b
      1 c
      1 d


df2 = A B C
      1 a apple
      1  cherry
      1 5 apple
      1 b orange
```

I want to merge these two dataframes based on A and B column. My logic is the following:

```
if df1['A'][0] is in df2['A'] and df1['B'][0] is in df2['B'] and they are equal:

      then create new column df1['New Product'] = df2['C']
```

I need to create the third column in `df1` if this condition is met.

I tried hard but without any success. I guess index position matters.

This is my solution which does not work:

```
df1['New Product'] = df2['C'][(df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])) & (df1['B'].isin(df2['B']))]
```

The expected output should be:

```
df1 = A B C
      1 a apple
      1  cherry
      1 5 apple
      1 b orange
      1 c nan
      1 d nan
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: You want a left `merge` for this, `df.merge(df2, on = ['A','B'], how = 'left')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try simple left join,

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['A','B'],how='left').rename(columns={'C':'New Product'})
```

O/P:

```
   A  B New Product
0  1  a       apple
1  1         cherry
2  1  5       apple
3  1  b      orange
4  1  c            
5  1  d
```

Comment: Same here, when I perform this merge the length of new `df` is more than the length of original `df1`

Comment: @NodarOkroshiashvili- it means that your df2 has duplicate values in key column, first remove that using df2=df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B']) then perform the above code

Comment: Thanks, man, that perfectly works. I did this but seems I missed something

Answer (score 1):

you need:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1]*6, 'B':['a',None,5,'b','c','d']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1]*4, 'B':['a', None, 5, 'b'], 'C':['apple','cherry','apple','orange']})

df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['A','B'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
 A     B       C                                                                                                                    
0  1     a   apple                                                                                                                    
1  1  None  cherry                                                                                                                    
2  1     5   apple                                                                                                                    
3  1     b  orange                                                                                                                    
4  1     c     NaN                                                                                                                    
5  1     d     NaN
```

Comment: Seems to work but after this the length of new `df` increases but I do not need this